# Url rerwriting using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i have a url (http://www.example.com/item/?items=26) and i want (http://www.example.com/item/items/26) using htaccess, please any one can help
Thanks

Comment: try like this. 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^item/(.*)$ item/items=$1 [L]

Comment: @user3297972 did you tried the answer given by me ? It should work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^items=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /item/items/%1? [L]
```

You can also use this to make it more generic:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /item/%1/%2? [R=302,L]
```

This will check any key and it's value as only numeric.

Reference: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Comment: @KailashYadav i have used your second code this will redirect to http://www.example.com/items/26 but i need http://www.example.com/item/items/26 here is my code

Comment: code 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /item/%1/%2? [R=302,L]
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>

Comment: @user3297072 there must be someother rule which is messing up. Goto this site: `http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/` and enter this as `http://domain.local/item/?items=26` enter htaccess as`RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)=(\d+)$ RewriteRule ^(.*) /item/%1/%2? [R=302,L]` and click on check now